# Adding a link when Admin is loged in in PHP

Tags: php

So I was able to make a code work where if the user is an Admin in the database, the link 'ADMIN' shows. However, when no one is logged in, it shows that part of the code to determine if the user is admin is undefined index.

How do I make it so that it doesnt show the undefined index when no one is logged in?

```
    <?php 

session_start();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/masthead.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav> 
        <div class="brand">


            <h1><a href="index.php">HOME PAGE</h1></a></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="books.php">BOOKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="stories.php">STORIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="quotes.php">QUOTES</a></li>
                <li><a href="upload.php">UPLOAD</a></li>
                <li><a href="Register.php">REGISTER</a></li>
                <li><a href="email.php">CONTACT ME</a></li>
     <?php 
$dbserverName = "localhost";
$dbuserName = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "database";


$db = mysqli_connect( $dbserverName , $dbuserName , $dbpassword , $dbname );

$value = $_SESSION['u_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT admin, user_id FROM users WHERE username='".$value."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $u_admin = $row['admin'];

        if ($u_admin === "Y") {


    print '<li><a href="admin.php">admin</a></li>';
        }
    }
     ?>
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
  print '<form action = "includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="logout">LOGOUT</button>
  </form>';
}

else {
  print '<form action = "includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="logout">LOGIN</button>

</form>';
}
?>
            </ul>     
    </nav>
    <section class="sec1"></section>
    <section class="sec2"></section>
    </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

  <main container class="siteContent">
  <!-- BEGIN CHANGEABLE CONTENT. -->`enter code here`
```

I am stuck....I have tried different if statements with a variable equal to true instead...but that doesnt work.

I forgot to add the the error is at when I run the code. It doesnt show when the user is logged in, just when no one is logged in.

```
$value = $_SESSION['u_id'];
```

Comment: Use $u_admin == "Y", not ===, also, set $u_admin = "" at the top of the page to stop undefined variable and prevent issues

Comment: @clearshot66 what difference does using a loose comparison make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if array values are set before using them. Something like this
`$u_admin = isset($row['admin']) ? $row['admin']  : false`

If you are using php 7, you can shorten this with the null coalescing operator
`$u_admin = $row['admin'] ?? false`

This assigns your variable if it's set, otherwise it assigns it as the second value.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that's causing the error?

Comment: Undefined index: u_id in header.php on line 39 and 39 is: $value = $_SESSION['u_id'];

Comment: Ah ok, I read it as the error being caused by the if statement. In that case you want to change that to `$u_admin = $row['admin'] ?: false`

Comment: Still giving the undefined index for u_id when one isnt logged in.

Comment: Oops, I have updated my answer above with hopefully some more useful info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170250/discussion-between-user4839691-and-graeme-chapman).